# How to change log level in Azure Functions

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, quarkus

We are working on several Quarkus (2.5.4 at the time of writing) applications that are deployed to Azure Function Apps.

We've noticed that all our logs, regardless of severity in code, show up as info in application insights.

```java
public class ExampleClass {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleClass.class);

    public void welcome(@NotNull String name) {
        logger.trace("TRACE hello to {}", name);
        logger.debug("DEBUG hello to {}", name);
        logger.info("INFO hello to {}", name);
        logger.warn("WARN hello to {}", name);
        logger.error("ERROR hello to {}", name);
    }
}
```

We've added the jboss log manager to our dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I then check the logs, it shows up as such

> 2022-02-24T07:58:14.325 [Information] 2022-02-24T07:58:14.308 [INFO] INFO hello to name
> 2022-02-24T07:58:14.325 [Information] 2022-02-24T07:58:14.308 [WARN] WARN hello to name
> 2022-02-24T07:58:14.325 [Information] 2022-02-24T07:58:14.308 [ERROR] ERROR hello to name

As you can see, Azure somehow misinterprets our log severity and makes everything show up at the info level.

The first part of every line (like `2022-02-24T07:58:14.325 [Information]`) is added by Azure, while the rest of the line is what Quarkus logs to console.

I understand why the first two log entries don't show up, because we set the minimum level to INFO.

From what I understand from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#autocollected-logs), Azure would automatically recognize the logs. However, this does not appear to be the case for us.

Is there something we've forgotten?

Comment: What do you mean? I see [INFO], [WARN], and [ERROR] in the logs you have shown? @Cas

Comment: @SMA yeah that's the log format that Quarkus uses. However, Azure puts its own stuff in front, including [Information]. That's the log level that it eventually uses in things like log analytics. It's like it doesn't recognize the Quarkus format and just assumes everything is info.

Comment: have you tried to log using the function `ExecutionContext`? `ctx.getLogger().` there you have all the granularity

Comment: I don't think we have access to the execution context because it's hidden by the quarkus azure http functions extension. I'll check again to make sure, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first part of every line (like `2022-02-24T07:58:14.325 [Information]`) is added by Azure

**The `[Information]` can be added in a log stream by default.**

#### Built-in log stream:

A log Stream is used to view a stream of your application log files. This is equivalent to the output seen when you debug your functions during local development. All log-based **information** is displayed in a Log Stream window.

#### Stream log:

Before you stream logs in real-time, enable the log type that you want to list. Any **information** written to files ending in **.txt, .log, or .htm** that are stored in the `_/LogFiles_` directory (`d:/home/logfiles`) is streamed by App Service.
Whatever is written in the log files can be displayed in a Log Stream.

local
[image]
In portal log Stream
[image]
In the above screenshots, you can check whatever is written in a local log that can be added to a Log Stream. By default, the `running time and [Information]` are always available in a log Stream (Every new line in a log file that is added with `2022-02-24T14:40:46.015 [Information] logline` in a log Stream)

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#stream-logs) for more information

Comment: Ah, thanks. So if I understand correctly; the [Information] tag added in the log stream is unrelated to the parsed severity level?

Comment: @Cas, yes it is not related to severity level.